# Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, tex, tex-live

I've already installed LaTeX via pip and I've also installed the software from http://www.tug.org/.
But still, I can't design a plot using ChainConsumer and it gives me the error "Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found."
What can I do to solve the problem?

**here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
!pip install chainconsumer
!pip install latex
from chainconsumer import ChainConsumer
df2= pd.read_csv('height_weight.csv')
params = ["weight", "height"]
m = df2['sex']==1
male = df2.loc[m, params].values
female = df2.loc[~m, params].values
c = ChainConsumer()
c.add_chain (male , parameters = params, name = "male", kde = 1.0, color = "r")
c.add_chain (female , parameters = params, name = "female", kde = 1.0, color = "b")
c.configure (contour_labels = "confidence")
c.plotter.plot(figsize = 2.0)
```

****and here's the error:****

````
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    274         try:
--> 275             report = subprocess.check_output(command,
    276                                              cwd=self.texcache,

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    414 
--> 415     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    416                **kwargs).stdout

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    492 
--> 493     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    494         try:

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    857 
--> 858             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    859                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1310             try:
-> 1311                 hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1312                                          # no special security

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-72dee424e2e7> in <module>
      7 c.add_chain (female , parameters = params, name = "female", kde = 1.0, color = "b")
      8 c.configure (contour_labels = "confidence")
----> 9 c.plotter.plot(figsize = 2.0)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chainconsumer\plotter.py in plot(self, figsize, parameters, chains, extents, filename, display, truth, legend, blind, watermark, log_scales)
    203                         h = None
    204                         if p1 in chain.parameters and p2 in chain.parameters:
--> 205                             h = self._plot_contour(ax, chain, p1, p2, color_extents=color_param_extents)
    206                         cp = chain.config["color_params"]
    207                         if h is not None and cp is not None and cp not in cbar_done:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chainconsumer\plotter.py in _plot_contour(self, ax, chain, px, py, color_extents)
   1193             else:
   1194                 fmt = dict([(l, "%d\\%%" % (100 * l)) for l in lvls])
-> 1195             ax.clabel(con, lvls, inline=True, fmt=fmt, fontsize=self.parent.config["contour_label_font_size"])
   1196         return h
   1197 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in clabel(self, CS, levels, **kwargs)
   6356             All other parameters are documented in `~.ContourLabeler.clabel`.
   6357         """
-> 6358         return CS.clabel(levels, **kwargs)
   6359 
   6360     #### Data analysis

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in clabel(self, levels, fontsize, inline, inline_spacing, fmt, colors, use_clabeltext, manual, rightside_up, zorder)
    196             blocking_contour_labeler(inline, inline_spacing)
    197         else:
--> 198             self.labels(inline, inline_spacing)
    199 
    200         self.labelTextsList = cbook.silent_list('text.Text', self.labelTexts)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in labels(self, inline, inline_spacing)
    557             con = self.collections[icon]
    558             trans = con.get_transform()
--> 559             lw = self.get_label_width(lev, self.labelFmt, fsize)
    560             lw *= self.axes.figure.dpi / 72  # scale to screen coordinates
    561             additions = []

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py in get_label_width(self, lev, fmt, fsize)
    244         lev, ismath = text.Text()._preprocess_math(lev)
    245         if ismath == 'TeX':
--> 246             lw, _, _ = (texmanager.TexManager()
    247                         .get_text_width_height_descent(lev, fsize))
    248         elif ismath:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    421         else:
    422             # use dviread.
--> 423             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    424             with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
    425                 page, = dvi

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    307             texfile = self.make_tex(tex, fontsize)
    308             with cbook._lock_path(texfile):
--> 309                 self._run_checked_subprocess(
    310                     ["latex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "--halt-on-error",
    311                      texfile], tex)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    277                                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    278         except FileNotFoundError as exc:
--> 279             raise RuntimeError(
    280                 'Failed to process string with tex because {} could not be '
    281                 'found'.format(command[0])) from exc

RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    274         try:
--> 275             report = subprocess.check_output(command,
    276                                              cwd=self.texcache,

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    414 
--> 415     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    416                **kwargs).stdout

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    492 
--> 493     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    494         try:

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    857 
--> 858             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    859                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1310             try:
-> 1311                 hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1312                                          # no special security

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    246 
    247     if 'png' in formats:
--> 248         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    249     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    250         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    130         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
    131 
--> 132     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    133     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    134     if fmt == 'svg':

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2191                            else suppress())
   2192                     with ctx:
-> 2193                         self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2194 
   2195                     bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1861 
   1862             self.patch.draw(renderer)
-> 1863             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
   1864                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1865 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    129     if not_composite or not has_images:
    130         for a in artists:
--> 131             a.draw(renderer)
    132     else:
    133         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py in wrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    409                          else deprecation_addendum,
    410                 **kwargs)
--> 411         return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    412 
    413     return wrapper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2745             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2746 
-> 2747         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2748 
   2749         renderer.close_group('axes')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    129     if not_composite or not has_images:
    130         for a in artists:
--> 131             a.draw(renderer)
    132     else:
    133         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1163 
   1164         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
-> 1165         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1166                                                                 renderer)
   1167 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
   1089     def _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer):
   1090         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
-> 1091         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1092                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1093                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1089     def _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer):
   1090         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
-> 1091         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1092                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1093                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    900 
    901         with cbook._setattr_cm(self.figure, dpi=dpi):
--> 902             bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    903             x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
    904             x, y = self.get_transform().transform((x, y))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    285 
    286         # Full vertical extent of font, including ascenders and descenders:
--> 287         _, lp_h, lp_d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
    288             "lp", self._fontproperties,
    289             ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    225             texmanager = self.get_texmanager()
    226             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
--> 227             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
    228                 s, fontsize, renderer=self)
    229             return w, h, d

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    421         else:
    422             # use dviread.
--> 423             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    424             with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
    425                 page, = dvi

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    307             texfile = self.make_tex(tex, fontsize)
    308             with cbook._lock_path(texfile):
--> 309                 self._run_checked_subprocess(
    310                     ["latex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "--halt-on-error",
    311                      texfile], tex)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    277                                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    278         except FileNotFoundError as exc:
--> 279             raise RuntimeError(
    280                 'Failed to process string with tex because {} could not be '
    281                 'found'.format(command[0])) from exc

RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found

<Figure size 432x432 with 4 Axes>```
````

Comment: Hey there! Is it possible to create a more [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can see where the actual problem is and not the whole code. Thanks :)!

Comment: I would say don't use `pip` to install packages that are available through `conda` when using the Anaconda distribution. `conda install -c conda-forge miktex` or `conda install -c samreay chainconsumer`

Comment: thanks for your comment Trenton,
I did what you said but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [open issue in ChainConsumer](https://github.com/Samreay/ChainConsumer/issues/78), and can be fixed by adding the `usetex = False` flag when configuring your plot.

In your example:

```py
c.configure(usetex=False,
            contour_labels = "confidence")
```